# Projectivity of torsion-free modules over integral group rings

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, modules

Let $G$ be a torsion-free group and assume that the integral group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$ is torsion-free as well. Let $M$ be a torsion-free, finitely generated module over $\mathbb{Z}G$.

If we assume that $M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}G} \mathbb{Q}G$ is a projective $\mathbb{Q}G$-module, can we conclude that $M$ itself is projective?

(For finite groups $G$ a somewhat similar question was already asked here: [Looking for criterion for $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules to be projective](https://mathoverflow.net/q/91151/13356).)

Comment: Group rings are always torsion-free.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Group rings over positive characteristic fields need not be torsion-free.  For a cyclic group $G = \langle g \rangle$ of order $p$ and for a field $k$ of characteristic $p$, $kG$ contains the nonzero element $1\underline{g} - 1 \underline{e}$ whose $p^{\text{th}}$ power equals $0$.

Comment: @Jason: is that what torsion-free means for a ring? I interpreted it to mean that the underlying abelian group is torsion-free. I don't think I would call nilpotents torsion.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I actually meant "ZG is a domain", not "ZG is torsion-free" (i.e., I assume the Kaplansky conjecture to be true). But let me leave it as it is, since it doesn't change that much (see Jason's answer).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: "Is that what torsion-free means for a ring?"  Of course this depends on your convention.  I am interpreting "torsion elements" to mean "nonzero zero-divisors".

Comment: @AlexE: "I actually mean 'ZG is a domain', not 'ZG is torsion-free' . . ."  In the example below $\mathbb{Z}G$ is an integral domain.  It is also Noetherian, regular and factorial.

Comment: @Jason: oh, I see, you mean that $R$ is torsion-free as an $R$-module. Got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is already false when $G$ equals $\mathbb{Z}$.  The group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$ is $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$.  Let $p$ be a prime integer, and let $I\subset \mathbb{Z}G$ be the ideal $\langle p, t-1 \rangle$.  Then $I\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}G}\mathbb{Q}G$ is isomorphic to the principal ideal $\langle t-1 \rangle$, which is free of rank $1$.  Yet associated to the short exact sequence, $$0 \to I \to \mathbb{Z}G \to \mathbb{Z}G/I \to 0,$$ consider the long exact sequence of $\text{Tor}_\bullet^{\mathbb{Z}G}(\mathbb{Z}G/I,-)$.  The second connecting map quickly gives that $$\text{Tor}_1^{\mathbb{Z}G}(\mathbb{Z}G/I,I) = \text{Tor}_2^{\mathbb{Z}G}(\mathbb{Z}G/I,\mathbb{Z}G/I) \cong \mathbb{Z}G/I$$ is nonzero.  Therefore $I$ is not projective.

**Edit.** I corrected this from Ext (incorrect) to Tor (correct).